# How can I add a module in the space shown in this picture in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

How can I add a module in the space shown in this picture? The green run button is disabled and I can't run the hello world app in my phone. I am using android studio 3.2.1.

[image]

Comment: where's the picture?

Comment: I formatted question and added his picture properly

Comment: @Redman good work

Comment: try invalidate cache and restart

Comment: Android Studio does not recognize your `app` as module. You likely imported the project incorrectly\